# Material ripple effect on Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-styles

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSubmitFeedback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvThankuText"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />
```

Is it possible to have a solution that can control adding ripple effect on view(TextView,ImageView etc) on tap using Styles and control at application level?